# SDL Web 8.5 with CWA

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5

Does SDL Web 8.5 support CWA? As mentioned in product documentation it's deprecated but will work.

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-9CA91AD6-7BD7-4B7F-B966-7FC05FBAF71B&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-07499C0F-E04D-4FEB-BA97-D655E2F148A9.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-9CA91AD6-7BD7-4B7F-B966-7FC05FBAF71B

Comment: As you have already highlighted, CWA will work with 8.5 (deprecated). Do you have a specific question regarding that?
Is there a specific reason that you are looking at DXA. DXA also have a JAVA web application(https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java).

Answer (score 1):

Deprecated, in general, means that something will work, but it's an outdated feature/module/functionality which will be dropped in one of the future releases. Definition of deprecated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation#Software_deprecation).

In other words, it should only be used for maintaining existing implementation and should be upgraded as soon as possible. Also, its a telltale for someone implementing said feature/module/functionality to take a different route. For example, in-process Content Delivery roles became deprecated after the introduction of the microservices architecture in Web 8.

Shiva in his answer already mentions some alternatives, I would suggest you to take a look at those.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already highlighted, CWA will work with 8.5 (deprecated). Do you have a specific question regarding this? A high level but still relevant difference between CWA and DD4T is [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8539/difference-between-dd4t-and-cwa)

Is there a specific reason that you are looking at DXA? DXA also have a [JAVA web application](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java).

DD4T JAVA is also available but I would highly recommend moving to DXA due to the upcoming releases and the support from the SDL and community.